# Get particular imap folder names PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I need to get the imap folder names , and normally i do

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, SERVER, "*");
if (is_array($list)) {
    foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
        echo "($key) ";
        echo imap_utf7_decode($val->name) . ",";
        echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
        echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

It will give us an array of mailbox names , but what i need to get is particular mailbox names.

Ex : for email sent items some servers gives me `Sent Items` and some others `Sent`. So it depending on the server.

My requirement is i need to search for `Inbox` and `Sent Items`.

What is the most preferable way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very tricky question. The folder name is totally `dependent on servers implementation`. Different mailers have a different patterns for names of the folders. If you are planning to use this code for generic purpose then there is `no solution` to it. There is no way to identify the folder type by its name.

Even for specific mailers its difficult to identify the Sent items folder because of following reasons:

> If you are planning to have a regex or pattern matching then the users are free to create a user folder with names like: Sent Ansh or SentMailAnsh or AnshSentMail
>
> Secondly Clients like Outlook(2010 i suppose) for IMAP gives you the flexibility to store the Sent Items mails in specific folders so even the System has a folder named "Sent Mails" the user might prefer to store these mails in a new folder named "AnshSend"

So I would recommend you to analyze the situation based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks , what i am currently doing is just putting the email folder names in a config file. User need to configure the folder names.